# Make ObjectAnimator animation duration independent of global animator duration scale setting in developer options

Tags: android, animation, duration, objectanimator, animator

How can you make ObjectAnimator independent of the "Animator duration scale" developer options setting when constant and unmodifiable speed is critical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use hidden API to access the `setDurationScale` method on the `ValueAnimator` object.

Comment: how did you did that? Could u pls post some example for help.

Answer (score 13):

I noticed there is no explicit answer for this. You can do this by calling the hidden API via reflection:

```
// Get duration scale from the global settings.
float durationScale = Settings.Global.getFloat(context.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, 0);

// If global duration scale is not 1 (default), try to override it
// for the current application.
if (durationScale != 1) {
  try {
    ValueAnimator.class.getMethod("setDurationScale", float.class).invoke(null, 1f);
    durationScale = 1f;
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    // It means something bad happened, and animations are still
    // altered by the global settings. You should warn the user and
    // exit application.
  }
}
```

For more details you can check this blog post: https://arpytoth.com/2016/12/20/android-objectanimator-independent-of-global-animator-duration/

Comment: Very nice this answer is still here as the linked domain has gone entirely offline and the Internet Archive doesn't have a copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to mess with setDurationScale, just do this

```
//in activity, kotlin
val animScale = Settings.Global.getFloat(this.contentResolver, Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, 1f)
animator.setDuration((timeInMs/animScale).toLong())
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue entirely as the user can turn off the animation, which sets the scale to 0. This would then fail.